# Odoo configuration file unicode issue

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-8

Hi I'm having an issue in my Docker Odoo installation. I am using xcgd/odoo image and I am trying to set `addons_path` using the configuration file.

Here is the content of the configuration file.

```
[options]

admin_passwd = lost-time-is-never-found-again

# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Port Options
# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# |
# | Define the application port and longpolling ports.
# |

xmlrpc_port = 8069

# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Database Configurations
# |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# |
# | Database configurations that setup Odoo to connect to a
# | postgresql database.
# |

db_host = db
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
db_port = 5432

#addons_path = /mnt/logic-addons,/mnt/data-addons

addons_path = /opt/odoo/sources/odoo/openerp/addons
```

Here is the error I am having

```
openerp: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/sources/odoo/openerp/addons']
```

I tried using `"` or `'` but it keeps giving me `u'` in front of my `addons_path`

I have tried using `# -*- coding: ascii -*-` but it has no effect

This behavior is not occuring in my other Docker container. I specifically used xcgd/odoo image just for the Odoo v8 image. Since official Odoo does not provide v8 image.

I have found no issue using official Odoo image (v12).

Can we tell python not to add `u'` in front of strings? Or is there any other way we can tell it just to treat the `addons_path` like ASCII

Comment: Not trying to offend, but does it matter that it's treating that as a Unicode string? Does it break anything? I've never noticed this happening, but you might be able to use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` rather than `# -*- coding: ascii -*-`

Comment: What is the real issue here? Seems Odoo runs fine with it.

Comment: Well if I comment the addon_path it works. When I uncomment Odoo server gives error cannot found web module. That is why I think it has something to do with the "u" in front of addon folder.

Comment: When I uncomment it gives the same addon folder just without the u in front.

Comment: I am trying to set it with Odoo default addon path plus two custom addon path folder. And yes I have confirmed the path is correct by ssh into the docker image and check the folders and files.

Comment: It is not a problem with Unicode, it didn't find the web module so check your files properly check if the web module is present in the addons path you provided. make sure is loading the correct path. but don't think of it as a unicode problem because this doesn't matter because obviously the list contains two valid paths.

Comment: Yes it seems I was wrong, `addons_path` worked now